# TASM, Assembly, can't change string, offset

Tags: string, assembly, x86-16, tasm

I try to change the string to the other one, but the output I get is broken.

How do I change string to the other one so it doesn't do this:

[image]

Intended output:

```
in rect
under line
out circ
```

Also, I do not know the purpose of "offset" in the code so it also can be the problem.

Also, I get some warnings when trying to assemble it and I don't know they mean:

[image]

The code:

```
.model small

.data
X    db 0
Y    db 0
var0 db 0

rect        db "out rect",13,10,"$"
rect_plus   db "in rect",13,10,"$"
line        db "under line",13,10,"$"
line_plus   db "above line",13,10,"$"
circ        db "out circ",13,10,"$"
circ_plus   db "in circ",13,10,"$"

.code
main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    jmp input

    input:
        ...        
        jmp rect_check1

    rect_check1:
        ...        
        jb  rect_check2
        jmp rect_print
    
    rect_check2:
        ...
        jb rect_change
        jmp rect_print
    
    rect_change:
        lea bx, rect;               <============== SOMETHING WRONG HERE
        mov [bx], offset rect_plus; <=========================== OR HERE
    
        jmp rect_print

    rect_print:
        mov dx, offset rect;        <=========================== OR HERE
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
    
        jmp line_check
    
    line_check:
        ...
        jb  line_change
        jmp line_print

    line_change:
        lea bx, line;               <=========================== OR HERE
        mov [bx], offset line_plus; <=========================== OR HERE
    
        jmp line_print

    line_print:
        mov dx, offset line;        <=========================== OR HERE
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
    
        jmp circ_check
    
    circ_check:
        ...        
        jb  circ_change
        jmp circ_print

    circ_change:
        lea bx, circ;               <=========================== OR HERE
        mov [bx], offset circ_plus; <=========================== OR HERE

        jmp circ_print

    circ_print:
        mov dx, offset circ;        <=========================== OR HERE
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

        jmp quit

    quit:
        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
end main
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  rect_change:
        lea bx, rect;               <============== SOMETHING WRONG HERE
        mov [bx], offset rect_plus; <=========================== OR HERE
        jmp rect_print
```

Your logic is wrong here.
`lea bx, rect` loads the offset of string `"out rect",13,10,"$"` to register `bx`. The offset in `bx` is then **0003h**. The next instruction tries to overwrite one or two bytes of memory at `ds:bx` (the letters "o" or "ou") with offset of another string `"in rect",13,10,"$"` (with binary number **000Eh**) which makes no sense. As you didn't specify how many bytes you're going to overwrite, TASM gives you the Warning.

Restructuralize your spaghetti code and make your subprocedures **callable** (ending with `ret`), for instance

```
line_print PROC ; Display the $-terminated string addressed with DS:DX.
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        ret
line_print ENDP
```

Then, whenever you want to display a string, load its offset to `dx` and call the subprocedure:

```
    mov dx,offset rect
    call line_print
    ; check the rectangle
    mov dx,offset rect_plus
    call line_print
```

Comment: "The offset in `bx` is then **4**". Are you sure about this 4? I see 3 byte-sized variables, so would expect `BX=3`.

Comment: @SepRoland Tnx, fixed.

Comment: This isn't spaghetti code, it's just full of confusing-looking noisy NOPs in the form of `jmp next_instruction` such as `jmp rect_print`.  Or `jb foo` / `jmp somewhere` / `foo:` instead of `jnb somewhere` / fall through.  Wrapping 2 instructions in a function seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed its unnecessary to you but it might help beginners to understand the logic of their program. I prefer **top-down** approach: first write the coarse skeleton using not-defined-yet calls or macroinvokations, and then pin down details. Effectiveness comes aboard only when everything works.